# ejecutar dos metodos desde el controlador codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mvc

estoy trabajando con codeigniter, y tengo un metodo el cual que va a dos funciones del modelo, el problema es que no realiza lo que dice en una de esas funciones, solo hace la primera.

codigo del controlador(el metodo que llama a dos funciones del modelo):

```
  public function approvedIncidence()
  {

    $postData = $this->input->post();
    $postNameAdvocate = $postData['advocateName'];
    $postDate = $postData['datepicker'];
    $postNewIn = $postData['newIn'];
    $postNewOut = $postData['newOut'];


    $postNumCase = $postData['CaseNumber'];
    $nameSesion = $this->session->name;
    $separation = ": ";
    $break = "\n";
    $postComment1 = $postData['Comment'];
    $postCommentNew = $postData['newComment'];
    $postComment = 
    $postComment1.$nameSesion.$separation.$postCommentNew.$break;
    $this->ol_model->approvedIncidence($postNumCase, 
    $postComment,$postDate,$postNewIn, $postNewOut,$postNameAdvocate);
    $this->ol_model->approvedIncidenceSch($postDate,$postNewIn, 
    $postNewOut,$postNameAdvocate);
    redirect('Admin/solvedIncidence');

     }
```

como pueden ver en la parte donde dice ol_model estoy haciendo referencia a las funciones del modelo.

codigo de las funciones del modelo:

```
   public function approvedIncidence($request_num_case, $request_comment){
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $array = array(
    'request_unread_rta' => '1',
    'request_resolution' => 'approved',
    'request_auth_date' => $date,
    'request_updated_by' => $this->session->name,
    'request_comment' => $request_comment
     );

     $this->db->where('request_num_case', $request_num_case);
     $this->db->update('ol_request', $array);

     }
```

esta es la que no ejecuta osea no actualiza los campos del array_sch:

codigo:

```
     public function approvedIncidenceSch($dates,$postNewIn, 
     $postNewOut,$postNameAdvocate){
     $array_sch = array('sch_actual_in' => $postNewIn,
     'sch_actual_out' => $postNewOut
      );
     $this->db->where('fk_roster_salesforcename', $postNameAdvocate);
     $this->db->where('sch_date', $dates);
     $this->db->update('ol_schedules', $array_sch);

       }
```

Comment: Algún error? Parece que estás pasando más parámetros de lo que acepta tu función. Fijate `$this->ol_model->approvedIncidence($postNumCase, 
    $postComment,$postDate,$postNewIn, $postNewOut,$postNameAdvocate);` y vos tenés en tu método `approvedIncidence($request_num_case, $request_comment)`.

Comment: me parece que el tema esta en acceder a la session dentro del model, prueba pasando `$this->session->name` desde el controller, si necesitas hacerlo si o si desde el modelo, lo cual no es aconsejable habras de pedir una instancia en el constructor del model, prueba lo primero si no funciona o necesitas lo segundo te armo un ejemplo de como pedir una instancia en el modelo . que version de codeigniter?

Comment: ya modifique el error de los parametros, tenias razon, pero aun asi no se soluciono, y lo de la session ps yo tengo otros metodos en las que la pongo exactamnete igual y no hay ningun problema. ademas ese metodo si funciona, el que no funciona es approvedIncidendeSch y ahi no tengo nada con $this->session->name

Comment: ok, vardump y print r a ver que le llega al model, no es muy elegante pero tiras un var_dump seguido de un die y ves que pasa con los datos que llegan (o no)

Comment: `var_dump($this->db->last_query());` es útil también en estos casos

Comment: Podés hacer un `var_dump` de `$postDate`? Creo que tiene un formato incorrecto al que tenés en la DB.

Comment: ese var_dump lo hago en el modelo o en el controlado, donde deberia aparecer el resultado, cuando inspecciono el codigo, la verdad no manejo eso de los mensajes.

Comment: En el controlador.

Comment: donde deberia aparecer? no sale nada deberia salir en network cuando inspecciono el codigo y selecciono el metodo cierto?

Comment: Lo más fácil en Codeigniter es hacer: `var_dump($postDate); die();`, así evita mostrar la vista y no hace falta que inspecciones nada.

Comment: me salieron muchos errores, variables indefinidas,A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice  

Message: Undefined index: advocateName

Filename: controllers/Admin.php

Line Number: 209

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\olPrueba2\application\controllers\Admin.php
Line: 209
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\olPrueba2\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once                                                                               y asi con cada una de las variavles  que estan en los corchetes de $postData

Comment: yo mando las variables por medio de un onclick en un formulario y sus id tienen el mismo nombre, no entiendo porque no estan definidas.